# I shouldn't think she did/does?

Tags: tense

Why is the following sentence correct grammatically?

> "Do you think she likes you?" --- "Well, no, I shouldn't think she did." (Lawrence, *Women in Love*)

I think this sentence should be like this:

> "Do you think she likes you?" --- "Well, no, I shouldn't think she does."

Why is the past tense "did" used in the first sentence?

Comment: This is an example of using the past tense in a conditional sentence to express the remoteness or unlikeliness of the hypothetical possibility. The sentence does sound odd to my ear, probably because it is from a century-old British novel.

Comment: Yes. This is an old fashioned way of expressing an unlikely hypothetical possibility, and was distinctly British.

Comment: Hypothetical possibility, I see! Thank you both!

Comment: This might be somewhat different than your example...  but the "unreal past" https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/unreal-past/ uses the past tense to discuss hypothetical possibilities, and it's not obsolete.